# Debugging a AWS lambda services created with .NET Core locally using AWS .NET Mock Lambda Test Tool

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I debug a AWS lambda services created with .NET Core locally using AWS .NET Mock Lambda Test Tool?

[image]

Comment: Show that have you tried ways to solve this problem.

Comment: I need solution for debugging a AWS lambda services created with .NET Core API locally using AWS .NET Mock Lambda Test Tool. I dont no how to proceed with this tool for Web API

Answer (score 1):

Are aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json and template configured correctly? If it is not, the function part may appear empty.

```
 {
  "Information": [
    "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI."
  ],
  "profile": "default",
  "region": "eu-central-1",
  "configuration": "Release",
  "framework": "netcoreapp3.1",
  "template": "serverless.template"
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the link with the information of what should go in that json? I've been looking for it, but have found nothing. I want to set the mock tool to take multiple functions, not just one.